# How to Create Screen Tabs in j2me (java)

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0

i have a Requiremenmt to create my Screen as Screen Tabs,when tab1 is Clicked Tab1 related List Screen Should be Displayed,when tab2  is Clicked tab2 related List Screen Should be Displayed?How Can we achieve this in j2me java,as i am new to j2me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not perform this directly on native Java ME Code. For such requirement you have an external GUI builder like [J2mepolish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/).  J2me polish uses CSS to design such gui. Have a look at to J2mepolish's [tabbled form](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/lush-ui/visual-guide/gui-screen-tabbedform.html).

Comment: I am developing j2me(java) MIDP 2.0 App,Can i combine j2me polish with my app?if so ,How can i do?i think j2mepolish will be used in j2me web appplication?i am new to j2me

Comment: i know that part, what i am saying is, you are developing in pure j2me, you need to use gul builder like j2mepolish.

Comment: visit the j2mepolish's website and see how to integrate. its very easy

Comment: Hi,i have installed J2ME-Polish2.1.4 and netbeans j2me plugin ,after that i restared the ide,then i start creating j2me polish project,i eneterd project name and i clicked next button on ide,it is saying Unable to read selected devices - check your J2ME Polish installation. You will ‌​need at least J2ME Polish 2. ? Can i run j2me polish apps on Nokia Symbian Belle SdK 1.0 devices?

Comment: that error says that your polish is not properly installed. and for your second question, i haven't use Belle yet.